# oracle sql - N number of rows for for distinct value i

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Suppose I have TableA w/ ID column:

**TableA**

ID

1

2

3

I'm hoping to get N rows returned for each distinct id in **TableA** 
(example below is for N=3)

EXPECTED OUTPUT

ID       SEQ

1          1

1          2

1          3

2          1

2          2

2          3

3          1

3          2

3          3

Is this possible w/ a single SQL statement?

Thanks!!

Comment: this is too simple to ask here

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has not done **ANY** research

Answer (score 0):

To get only rows with single ID

```
SELECT * FROM tab_name WHERE col1 = N ORDER BY col2 [DESC]
```

To Get how many records under each id

```
SELECT id, count(*) as count FROM tab_name GROUP BY id
```

To get specific number of rows per specific ID

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT id, col2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.id ORDER BY col3) colX
     FROM tab_name t) outerT 
WHERE 
    outerT.colX < N + 1
```

Comment: thanks but i'm looking to return N rows for each distinct ID in TableA w/ single select statement

Comment: @user3713251 see my update - something like that, but I have not tested it